# submit post form values from jade to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, jade4j

I have such a form on my jade template

```
  form(action='/scheduler/save/' + project.Id, method='post')
                div.form-group
                    label.control-label.col-md-2 RecurringPattern
                    div.col-md-10
                        div#RecurringPatternControl
                div.form-group
                    label.control-label.col-md-2 StartDate
                    div.col-md-3
                        //input#StartDate.form-control
                        input(id='StartDate', class='form-control', value='#{project.StartDate} ', enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                div.form-group
                    div.col-md-offset-2.col-md-10
                        input(type="submit", value="Save").btn.btn-lg.btn-success
```

and I want `StartDate` from input value in node js, I got`div#RecurringPatternControl`  from `req.body` but `StartDate` I can't get(( How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a "name" attribute in your input to be able to retrieve it later on. 
Just try adding something like

```
input(id='StartDate', name='startDate', class='form-control', value='#{project.StartDate} ', enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

It should work, if not try reviewing the whole POST header to see what's actually happening (and may be post it here if necessary)

Hope this helps !